# Overriding managed version warning when there's no parent pom

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

I have a pom that has a new dependency **NOT** being inherited from a parent, this is just a standalone pom. The dependency is this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The error warns of **"Overriding managed version 1.8.12 for micrometer-registry-prometheus"** that I do not see imported anywhere else. The only thing that is a micrometer that has 1.8.12 is shown in the dependency tree like so:

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.6.14:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.14:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.6.14:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.4:compile
|  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.8.12:compile
|     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
|     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
+- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:jar:1.9.5:compile
|  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:jar:0.12.0:compile
|     \- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.12.0:compile
|        +- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_otel:jar:0.12.0:compile
|        |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_common:jar:0.12.0:compile
|        \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_otel_agent:jar:0.12.0:compile
```

According to the tree, these are the only two places within the tree that has anything from io.micrometer.

Is the micrometer-core from spring-boot-starter-actuator somehow managing the micrometer-registry-prometheus? What's the best way to find out where this warning is coming from and resolve it?

Comment: please share the exat error message

Comment: Simplest solution is to define the micrometer dependencies in dependencyManagement before the spring-boot-starter-actuator...

Comment: I ended up moving it to dependencyManagement even though I felt like it should've worked without? Thanks @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here: either to use v1.9.5 or v1.8.12 of `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus`

To use v1.9.5 only exclude `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus` from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator` as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

To use only v1.8.12 remove the dependency on `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus`.

Comment: prometheus itself isn't a transitive dependency of the actuator (according to ```dependency:tree``` so excluding didn't work... quite confusing why i'm even getting a warning